# "award" passive voice. Put the word in brackets into the correct passive form

Tags: passive-voice

After (award) a medal for bravery, he became a local hero.
Help me with this one please, I don't understand it.

Comment: After being awarded.....

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you know what the passive voice is?

Comment: I know what it is, but I don't know how to make up a passive voice sentence with the word "award". After being awarded a medal for bravery, he became a local hero. Help me with this one please, I don't understand it. Or what?

Comment: I assume you know that *[to] **award*** here is a VERB, meaning ***to give** [a medal, a prize,...]*. But the subject here ("he") doesn't ***give*** anything - something ***is given to*** him (by an unspecified "giver"). Your example could be rephrased as *After **he was awarded** a medal for bravery...*, which is also "passive" ("he" is the ***object*** of the verb, but the ***subject*** - the one who ***does*** the awarding - isn't explicitly specified). Does that help?